# How to make empty show in front

Tags: modeling, bones, transparency

Just want to find a way for this empty to be in front of the character I have(kind of like x-ray)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with any object. Just enable "In Front" under the "Viewport Display" inside the "Object Properties" tab.

[image]