# Grease pencil stroke disappeared while sculpting

Tags: sculpting, grease-pencil

[image: screen capture]

I'm trying to sculpt the human body, and the reference showed the flow of muscle using a grease pencil. As you can see, the purple and red line shows the muscle around the neck.

However, when I sculpt for about hours, these lines disappear even if they are turned on the scene collection. Also, the Object visibility of 'Grease pencil' is also turned on. Is there any suggestion on how to see the grease pencil line again?

I wish I upload this blender file, but this file is included in the paid tutorial, so I'm so sorry that I cannot upload the file.

Thank you for your help, in advance.

Comment: Hello ! Did you use a Grease Pencil *object* (Add > Grease Pencil > Stroke) or a grease Pencil *annotation* (Shortcut D + left click and drag) ?

Comment: This is Grease Pencil Object. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223734/86891

Comment: I tried that option now, but it did not show the grease pencil. Maybe I should be careful when sculpting next time... Thank you for your advice.